Update an existing kubernetes aws-auth configmap with terraform
I am trying to update an existing config map of an EKS cluster with terraform. The cluster is deployed with terraform aws module :
module "eks" {
  source                                   = "terraform-aws-modules/eks/aws"
  version                                  = ">= 20.23"
  .
  .
  .
}

https://registry.terraform.io/modules/terraform-aws-modules/eks/aws/20.31.1
The configmap (aws-auth) is deployed by EKS automatically and is not defined by my terraform code.
The data addition will be as below in yaml format:
mapUsers: |
  - groups:
      - system:masters
    userarn: arn:aws:iam::516161651:user/myuser
    username: myuser

I am keeping this info in yaml file and want to pass it to terraform null_resource as follows:
data "template_file" "configmap_file" {
  template = "${file("${path.module}/configmap-values.yaml")}"
}
    
resource "null_resource" "your_deployment" {
  triggers = {
     manifest_sha1 = "${sha1("${data.template_file.configmap_file.rendered}")}"
}
    
provisioner "local-exec" {
  command = "kubectl patch cm mycm -n kube-system --patch-file -<<EOF\n${data.template_file.your_template.rendered}\nEOF"
  }
}

And I am having error below:

│ Error running command 'kubectl patch cm aws-auth -n kube-system --patch-file <<EOF
│ data:
│   mapUsers: |
│     - groups:
│       - system:masters
│       userarn: arn:aws:iam::516161651:user/myuser
│       username: myuser
│ EOF': exit status 1. Output: << was unexpected at this time.

Do you have any suggestions? I can use Helm if there is a way to update it with helm as well.
Note: The Kubernetes provider doesn't inject data into existing configmap as I understood after some research.

Why aren't you using proper terraform resources? https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/kubernetes/latest/docs/resources/config_map

Because that's a configmap deployed by EKS and not by terraform code. The Kubernetes provider doesn't inject data into existing configmap as I have understood.

Can you share how the EKS cluster is created? Did you use terraform for that as well?

@MoonHorse I would still import the config map into terraform

@MarkoE , I have added more info about the source code. I am using https://registry.terraform.io/modules/terraform-aws-modules/eks/aws/20.31.1 .

Although that is true, you can influence the roles/users mapping however, as described here: https://github.com/terraform-aws-modules/terraform-aws-eks/tree/master/modules/aws-auth#aws-auth-module.

@MarkoE, that seems like a solution, I will test it!

Since some of the module call code is missing, I would suggest trying something along the lines of:
module "eks" {
  source   = "terraform-aws-modules/eks/aws"
  version  = ">= 20.23"
  .
  .
  .

  aws_auth_users = [
    {
      userarn  = "arn:aws:iam::516161651:user/myuser"
      username = "myuser"
      groups   = ["system:masters"]
    }
  ]

}

This should only update the existing ConfigMap.

When I am testing it , I am having"   on ......\modules\eks\provider.tf line 22, in provider "kubernetes":    22:   load_config_file       = false" error from the kubernetes provider.

And if you comment that line out?

When I comment out, I cannot authenticate to eks avec kubectl. I need to check that.
